# Jquery returns [object object] when trying to manipulate dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to dynamically insert html fragment(input element) into an already existing div node.

I need to create three input elements, so I am using a loop to create them and initialize them via jquery. I am storing the created elements in a variable called htmlstr.

```
 var Buildstorecontents = function Buildstorecontents ()
    {

      var $parts_holder = $("#parts_holder");
      var $htmlstr = "";
      for(var i = 0; i < 3; i += 1)
      {
        $htmlstr += $("<input />", {
          "type"  : "text",
          "class" : "",
          "readonly"  : true
         }).append($("<br />"));
      }
      console.log($htmlstr);
      $parts_holder.append($htmlstr);
     }
     Buildstorecontents();
```

The problem is the variable htmlstr isn't holding the created html node but rather [object object]. What is the mistake I am making and other possible ways to do this?

This is what I am trying to achieve

```
<div id="parts_holder">        
  <input type="text" class="" readonly/><br /> 
  <input type="text" class="" readonly/><br />
  <input type="text" class="" readonly/><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to concatenate a jQuery object to a string. This won't work, because a jQuery object does not have a useful `toString` value.

You need to create an empty jQuery collection, `add` the elements to that, and then append that collection.

```
  var $html = $();
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i += 1)
  {
    $html = $html.add($("<input />", {
      "type"  : "text",
      "class" : "",
      "readonly"  : true
     })).add($("<br />"));
  }
  console.log($html);
  $parts_holder.append($html);
```

Comment: @A.Wolff No, because `add` modifies the collection. You can do that; it won't do any harm. But it's not necessary.

Comment: I was thinking add() to no modify collection, now i need to check ;)

Comment: Well, this is not really what i have: http://jsfiddle.net/S24KG/  Do i miss something?

Comment: This is in DOC: `the .add() method creates a new set and leaves the original set in pdiv unchanged`  pdiv beeing just an example used in DOC http://api.jquery.com/add/

Comment: interesting, looking at @Justin Niessner solution compared to the approach I am taking which is the more effective way to create html fragments.

Comment: @lboyel To create HTML fragments, what Justin suggests. But you're working with the DOM, so creating HTML fragments isn't *necessarily* what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is expecting the result of the jQuery operations to be a string.

You should create your entire HTML string before passing it to jQuery:

```
var htmlString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    htmlString += "<input type='text' class='' readonly /><br />";
}
$parts_holder.append($(htmlString));
```

It will cut down on the number of individual DOM manipulations performed by jQuery and speed everything up.

And just in case you want to see things in action:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QD44q/)