# Appending HTML Dynamically with Jquery returns [Object object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to define some basic HTML:

```
<ul id="menu" style="display:none">
    <li><a class="actions" href="1">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="actions" href="2">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="actions" href="3">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

And append it dynamically using jquery like so:

```
$('#container').append($('#menu')).show()
```

However all that's returned is the physical Object:

```
<div id="container">[object Object]</div>
```

Can my `menu` div be appended in this fashion?

UPDATE: Revised where the `show()` is placed, but outcome remains the same

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tbk2cLfL/ Works to me....

Comment: If you can, post your actual code (pastebin.org if needed) so that I can see what's going on, but it seems weird.

Comment: Make sure to have your js code *after* the html, or use $(document).ready()

Answer (score 1):

While this might work, I would probably run .show() AFTER you append the items to the page. The .append does not expect a function, it's just expecting a DOM element, which may be the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (tried with jQuery 1.6 -> 2.1.3) Did you use a simplified code example in your question? I suspect you are using a string concatenation somewhere like in this thread: [Jquery returns [object object] when trying to manipulate dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105127/jquery-returns-object-object-when-trying-to-manipulate-dom)

Comment: Yes I did include a simplified code sample. I'll update my question

Comment: Still cannot reproduce (it appends content but the content does not get shown, so output is empty).
You should try to create a JsFiddle where you reproduce your issue consistently, then share it here so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This way it should work:

```
$('#container').append( $('#menu').show() );
```